# Necessity of Identity Test in equals method

Tags: java, equals, apache-commons, compareto

**EDIT: Heart of the Matter**

When would an Identity Test pass, when the rest of a traditional equals method would fail? Is this added just to save the time of doing extra work?

---

**Original Post**

I am utilizing the [CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) from [org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) in a class I am testing. I notice that the [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) requires the following code to be explicitly called BEFORE calling the equals builder.

```
if (obj == this) { return true; } // Identity test
```

Such logic also appears in the Eclipse auto-generated equals method. I am attempting to use [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) methodology by having my `equals` method simply call my `compareTo` method and test equivalence to 0.

One question is whether I need to include the above code in my equals method, add it to my compareTo method or if it is already covered by [CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html). I notice that [CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) checks the equivalence of the parameters passed but does not recieve any direct references to the original lhs (this) and rhs (Object obj). That leads me to think that it is an oversight I should correct in my compareTo method.

**My largest issue is that I cannot seem to devise a potential test case in which `obj == this` but `this.compareTo(obj) != 0`.** Only thing that comes to mind is in an improperly implemented compareTo, sending in obj with one of its instance variables null could return a non-zero number if it is not first checked to see if the corresponding variable in `this` is also null. (Ran into this yesterday).

**Sample equals method:**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && obj instanceof MyClass)
        return this.compareTo((MyClass)obj) == 0;
    return false;
}
```

**Sample compareTo method**

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyClass other) {
return new CompareToBuilder()
    .append(this.getParam1(), other.getParam1())
    .append(this.getParam2(), other.getParam2())
    .toComparison();
}
```

Comment: Confused.  If `obj==this` you want `compareTo` to be 0.  It's the same object.

Comment: Ideally, that is the end goal. To be sure, I want to try to break the code by passing something that would fail to give the proper response unless `if (obj == this) { return true; }` is in there.

Comment: It may be of note that I have purposely omitted the call to `appendSuper` as the super class for `MyClass` does not overwrite `equals` or `compareTo` and there is nothing I can do about it. (different dev team).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the documentation for [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), `compareTo()` requires that

```
x.compareTo(y) == -y.compareTo(x)
```

Therefore, if `x == y`, `x.compareTo(x) == -x.compareTo(x)` and thus `x.compareTo(x) == 0`. So the only way to make `x == y && x.compareTo(y) != 0` is to break the `compareTo()` contract.

Note that, in my understanding, the `obj == this` test tends to be added to `equals()` methods as an optimization to keep from evaluating a deep comparison when unnecessary and does not affect the result of the call. (See Effective Java 2nd Ed, Item 8.) I assume the same holds true for the `compareTo()` method here.

Comment: Brilliant breakdown! I love the use of the compareTo contract to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 1):

> When would an Identity Test pass, when the rest of a traditional equals method would fail? Is this added just to save the time of doing extra work?

The short answer is: never.

The identity test is a cheap optimization intended as a quick way out of the rest of the equals() method.  In fact, Joshua Bloch recommends that every equals() method begin with just such a test as an optimization (Effective Java, 2nd Ed.).

Mr. Bloch recommends the following general structure for equals():

1. Use the == operator to check if the argument is a reference to this object. If it is, return true.
2. Use the instanceof operator to check if the argument is of the correct type. If it is not, then return false.
3. Cast the argument to the correct type.
4. For each significant field in the class, check if that field of the argument matches the corresponding field of this object.
5. and etc.

Comment: Just read an enlightening article debating the use of instanceof in an equals method. Long story short it is likely to violate the equals contract unless the class/method is made final. Better to use getClass() == other.getClass(). She specifically references Mr. Blochs example in her article. http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals.html

Comment: Other than the above noted objection, thanks for the confirmation that it is just an optimization.

Comment: I don't disagree.  Bloch covers some of these same points.  In fact, I blame equals() for ruining what should be seamless inheritance of strongly heritable child classes.  Adding new value elements to a subclass destroys the equals() contract, even for classes with strong is-a relationships such as the Point and ColorPoint classes used as example in Effective Java.... And the whole "favor composition over inheritance" schtick does nothing to help me not hate equals().

Comment: 5 years of Computer Science classes in college, 3 years in HS and today is the first I am hearing of these books.. Several times on several sites.. I am beginning to have that you-completely-missed-the-boat feeling.

Comment: Bloch was there at the beginning and participated at high levels in the development of the language.  It's hard to read his book and not think of him as having a very authoritative voice.  It's probably true that few other people have as much of an in-depth understanding of Java.  His book stands apart from other, similar books for its emphasis on real, usuable, practical advice that you can put to use almost immediately.  And you just can't escape from the sense that he really, truly, deeply knows what he's talking about.

Comment: @scottb: What problem is there with the rule "Two objects of distinct classes may only compare equal if they inherit from a common class which mandates the equality-testing behavior of all its subclasses"?  All instances of a derived class are guaranteed to differ from instances of the parent class in at least one way (their type); unless the parent class specifies that derived classes are only supposed to use certain properties in deciding equality, and type is not among the properties to use, the fact that object's type differs should imply that they are not equal.

Comment: @supercat: There is no problem with the rule.  You're free to declare an interface with any contract you please, eg. "equatable".  The rule only has to be feasible for your use case.  If you're talking about the contract for the `equals()` method of class `Object` though, your rule can never be true, esp. if the subclasses possess their own value components.

Comment: @scottb: I should have said that the parent class must define a transitive definition for equality of subclasses.  A simple example of doing that would be to require that subclasses define a `bool equals2(Object other)` method that compares everything they know about, and then have the parent define its equals method to ensure `other` derives from the parent type and, if so, return `equals2(other) && other.equals2(this)`.

Comment: @scottb: BTW, the scenario where I was thinking of the "base-classed defined equality" as being appropriate would be with something like an `ImmutableMatrix` class with public methods including `int numRows()`, `numCols()`, `double ElementAt(int row, int column)`.  Any two immutable matrices could be compared by comparing all elements, but matrix types which know something about each other could avoid comparing irrelevant elements.

Answer (score 1):

> When would an identity test pass when a traditional equals fail?

Technically, if "traditional" also means "naive", then an object graph with a loop in it (e.g. A has an ivar that points to B which has an ivar that points to A) would pass the identity test, but a traditional equals implementation would go into an infinite loop.

I'm not sure if the Apache library would protect against this.

Comment: @AnthonyW - indeed.  Sorry about that - fixed.